# Google App Script - Add or Update Calendar Event

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Updating previous question with detailed example. I have a google sheet with three used columns (A: Event Title, B: Event Description, and D: Event Date). I want to create a new all day event on Google Calendar if none exists, and update the existing one if it already exists.

Here is the code I tried: I am getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDescription' of undefined

```
function updatecal(){
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_lmsj3r1ogsaafhc68gfalstdco@group.calendar.google.com');
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Data For Calendar");
  const rows = data.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    if (index === 0) return;
    var eventdate = data.getRange(index, 4, 1, 1).getValue();
    var eventtitle = data.getRange(index,1,1,1).getValue();
    var eventdescription = data.getRange(index,2,1,1).getValue();
    console.log(eventdate + eventtitle + eventdescription)
    const eventdate1 = new Date(eventdate)
    const events = cal.getEventsForDay(eventdate1);
    if (events.lenght == 0){
      var newevent = cal.createAllDayEvent(eventtitle,eventdate1,
    {description: eventdescription});
    } else {
      ev = events[0];
      ev.setDescription(eventdescription)
    }

  })

}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in line 13 inside the `if` statement. You wrote `lenght` instead of `length` If you fix that the code runs just fine and the calendar events are created without any problem.

```
function updatecal(){
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_lmsj3r1ogsaafhc68gfalstdco@group.calendar.google.com');
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Data For Calendar");
  const rows = data.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    if (index === 0) return;
    var eventdate = data.getRange(index, 4, 1, 1).getValue();
    var eventtitle = data.getRange(index,1,1,1).getValue();
    var eventdescription = data.getRange(index,2,1,1).getValue();
    console.log(eventdate + eventtitle + eventdescription)
    const eventdate1 = new Date(eventdate)
    const events = cal.getEventsForDay(eventdate1);
    if (events.length == 0){          //The error was in this line
      var newevent = cal.createAllDayEvent(eventtitle,eventdate1,
    {description: eventdescription});
    } else {
      ev = events[0];
      ev.setDescription(eventdescription)
    }

  })

}
```

References:

- [length()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

Comment: Unless, I'm missing something, there seems to be a conflict if a different event is scheduled for the same day.  This script successfully adds a new event and modifies it if the description changes, but if another event is subsequently scheduled for the same day, this script fails to add a new event to that day.

Comment: In fact, if a user tries to schedule a new event for the same day as a previous event with a different description than the original event, the event title remains the same, but the description changes.