# Add Additional All-Day Events to Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Based off of Fernando Lara's answer here  [Google App Script - Add or Update Calendar Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322743/google-app-script-add-or-update-calendar-event/73325010#comment135147780_73325010) I am trying to create new events on Google Calendar.  Here is my script:

```
function updateCal(){
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarID");
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const rows = data.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    if (index === 0) return;
    var eventdate = data.getRange(index, 4, 1, 1).getValue();
    var eventtitle = data.getRange(index,1,1,1).getValue();
    var eventdescription = data.getRange(index,2,1,1).getValue();
    console.log(eventdate + eventtitle + eventdescription)
    const eventdate1 = new Date(eventdate)
    const events = cal.getEventsForDay(eventdate1);
    if (events.length == 0){          //The error was in this line
      cal.createAllDayEvent(eventtitle,eventdate1,{description: eventdescription});
    } else {
      ev = events[0];
      ev.setDescription(eventdescription)
    }

  })

}
```

The above script is successful at adding a new event or modifying an existing event if the description changes.  There is one major flaw, however.  The script does not allow for the creation of another all-day event on a day that already has an existing event.  I tried deleting the original event from the spreadsheet manually and adding a new event for the same day with a different title and different description.  The title remained the same on Google Calendar, but the description changed.

I believe this line below is incorrect, but I am not sure how to fix it:

```
if (events.length == 0)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Order of Process:

- This script is run with a time-based trigger.
- Managers submit form if employee is absent, late, or leaving early.  The employee name is the Calendar event title.  The details (absent, late, or leaving early) are the description.
- Spreadsheet filters out responses to only find the last record of a given employee on a given date.  That way, if an employee's attendance status changes, only the last recorded status is evaluated.  (Therefore, the importance of being able to update status based on description which my script does currently.)
- Need to be able to schedule/record the attendance status of multiple employees for the same day. (The script does not currently perform this task.)
- While this could be done via manual entry on Google Calendar, I am using a Gravity Form linked to a Google spreadsheet.  The data gets entered and recorded.  A particular employee's attendance record can be better monitored with a spreadsheet.

Comment: Could you clarify the exact steps on how you are attempting to create another all-day event on a day that already has an existing event?

Comment: Will do so in original post.

Comment: Added Order of Process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your script, how about checking the event title? I guessed that your goal might be able to be achieved by checking both the event date and the event title.
- In your script, `getValue()` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function updateCal() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarID");
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [, ...rows] = data.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(([eventtitle, eventdescription, , eventdate]) => {
    console.log(eventdate + eventtitle + eventdescription)
    const eventdate1 = new Date(eventdate)
    const events = cal.getEventsForDay(eventdate1);
    if (events.length == 0 || (events.length > 0 && !events.some(e => e.getTitle() == eventtitle))) {
      cal.createAllDayEvent(eventtitle, eventdate1, { description: eventdescription });
    } else {
      ev = events[0];
      ev.setDescription(eventdescription)
    }
  });
}
```

- By this modification, `cal.createAllDayEvent` is run by checking both the event date and the event title.
- In your script, I guessed that you might have wanted to skip the header row. But, if you don't want to skip it, please modify `const [, ...rows] = data.getDataRange().getValues();` to `const rows = data.getDataRange().getValues();`.
- If you want to check the description, please modify `if (events.length == 0 || (events.length > 0 && !events.some(e => e.getTitle() == eventtitle))) {` to `if (events.length == 0 || (events.length > 0 && !events.some(e => e.getTitle() == eventtitle) && !events.some(e => e.getDescription() == eventdescription))) {`.

### Added:

From your following reply,

> One big problem, however. When I change the description of an event in the spreadsheet, the description does not change in the calendar as it did before.

How about the following modified script?

```js
function updateCal() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarID");
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [, ...rows] = data.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(([eventtitle, eventdescription, , eventdate]) => { // Now [eventtitle, eventdescription, eventdate] ?
    console.log(eventdate + eventtitle + eventdescription)
    const eventdate1 = new Date(eventdate)
    const events = cal.getEventsForDay(eventdate1);
    if (events.length == 0 || (events.length > 0 && !events.some(e => e.getTitle() == eventtitle) && !events.some(e => e.getDescription() == eventdescription))) {
      cal.createAllDayEvent(eventtitle, eventdate1, { description: eventdescription });
    } else {
      events.forEach(e => {
        if (e.getTitle() == eventtitle && e.getDescription() != eventdescription) {
          e.setDescription(eventdescription);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

- From your reply, if your current script is `rows.forEach(([eventtitle, eventdescription, eventdate]) => {`, please modify `rows.forEach(([eventtitle, eventdescription, , eventdate]) => {` to it.

Comment: Thank you for your help once again.  It is working now.  I changed your lines:    rows.forEach(([eventtitle, eventdescription, , eventdate]) => {
    console.log(eventdate + eventtitle + eventdescription) to: rows.forEach(([eventtitle, eventdescription, eventdate]) => {
    console.log(eventtitle + eventdescription + eventdate) because there was an extra comma and the order was different.  I also deleted column C in my spreadsheet so that the data is in consecutive columns.

Comment: One big problem, however.  When I change the description of an event in the spreadsheet, the description does not change in the calendar as it did before.

Comment: @Tainake are you able to review?  Multiple events can now be added, but description for already existing event is not being modified if the description changes on the spreadsheet.

Comment: @ScriptingNovice Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `One big problem, however. When I change the description of an event in the spreadsheet, the description does not change in the calendar as it did before.`, I added one more modified script. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  Working correctly.  For my current purposes, this ended up being the best answer.  Have new issue which I have not been able to solve.  Will post it later.

Comment: Keep running into issues.  Trying to resolve now.

Comment: @Tainake, I think the issues are resolved now, thank you.  Added a sub-question here if you are interested in exploring this project with me a little further. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76721642/add-update-multiple-days-to-google-calendar

Comment: @ScriptingNovice Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But, when I saw your new question, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussion. I believe your new question will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding of your question, here's the flow of your process:

1. If an employee does not exist based on the ***date***, add a `new event`.
2. If an existing employee has a new ***description***, `update the event`.
3. Repeat ***step 1*** and/or ***step 2*** for the rest of the other employees with the same ***date***.

Perhaps you could try the sample below as a **guide** for your actual project. This script will fetch all data from your `Sheet1` and iterate through each **row**. For each row of data, it will retrieve the `date` and fetch the current events based on the `date`. It will then check if the row's `employee` already exists or not.

If the employee does not exist yet, it will be added as a new **event**. On the other hand, if the employee already exists, the script will update the existing **event**. Since you are using a sheet, assuming the most updated data is at the bottom in incremental order, if there are multiple updates for the same `employee` but with different **descriptions**, the very last data in the sheet for that `employee` will be used as the updated event data.

### *Sample Tweaked Script*

I have broken down your script into manageable pieces for maintainability.

```
//Set this as a global variable for easy access
const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■"); 

function updateCal() {
  var sheetData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange().getValues();

  //remove sheet headers.
  sheetData.shift();

  sheetData.forEach(row => {
    var events = getEvents(new Date(row[3]));
    events.length == 0 && addEvent(row[0], row[1], row[3]); //Add the first event if the base 'date' has no events yet.
    var eventRecords = events.map(x => [x.getTitle(),x.getDescription(),x.getStartTime(),x.getId()]);//get current events from the base 'date' as an array.
    var currentEvent = eventRecords.filter(x => x[0] == row[0]);//Checks if the current row 'employee' already has an event or not yet.
    console.log(`Add "${row[0]}"?\n[${currentEvent.length == 0 ? //If current event exists.
                                      addEvent(row[0],row[1],row[3]) : //[true] add the event.
                                      updateEvent(currentEvent[0][3],row[0],row[1],row[3]) //otherwise [false] update the current event
                                     }]\nDescription: "${row[1]}"\nDate: "${row[3]}" `)});
}

function getEvents(date) {
  var events = cal.getEventsForDay(date);
  return events;
}

function updateEvent(eventID,title,eventDescription,date){
  var event = cal.getEventById(eventID);
  event.setDescription(eventDescription)
  event.setAllDayDate(new Date(date));
  return `"${title}" (id: ${eventID}) has been updated.`
}

function addEvent(title, eventDescription, date) {
  cal.createAllDayEvent(title, date, { description: eventDescription });
  return `"${title}" has been added as a New Event.`;
}
```

### *Demo*

- Dummy `Sheet1`:
   *(***E.g.*** "John Appleseed" has not been added yet & another "Jon Doe" exists but has an updated **description** which needs to be updated.)*

> [image]

- Current calendar **event** based on `date`: 
   *(It currently contains "Jon Doe" & its **description** is set to **Late**)*

> [image]

- After running the`updateCal()`: 
   *(Shows logs for review & readability.)*

> [image]

- The new **updated calendar events**:  
   *(**Jon Doe**'s **Description** has been updated to **Leaving Early** & **John Appleseed** has been added)*

> [image]

### *Reference*

- [How to Organize Your Code with Functions](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/organizing-code-with-functions/)
- [JavaScript Array shift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp)
- [JavaScript Array filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [JavaScript Array map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [Javascript Short Circuiting Operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-short-circuiting/)

Comment: Not sure why.  When I actually tried to run the script, I got an error this morning.  I ended up the script from @Tainake and it was working properly.