# How Can I Add/Update Events Spanning Multiple Days to Google Calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

My current script below, which Tainake has helped me with and which I have modified to change the color of the event based on Attendance Status, adds an All Day Event or updates an All Day Event if the description of an already existing event changes.

A form entry populates the data.  Currently, the form only adds or updates an event for a single day (usually the current day).  Now I would like to extend the functionality a bit further.  I am looking to create or update events that span multiple days in Google Calendar. I would like a manager to be able to schedule vacations for his workers or modify previous multiple-day events.  To do so now, he would have to submit a form multiple times, changing the date each time.

At this time, I am not looking to schedule recurring events. Additonally, I use the spreadsheet for gathering statistics as well, so I don't want to allow managers to edit the Calendar manually.

I can think of two options for achieving the desired results.  Here is what I am trying to figure out:

**Option 1:**
What needs to be changed in the script to allow multiple-day events to be added or updated on Google Calendar?  It is essential that if the description changes for a particular individual on a particular day (Note:  The name of the individual serves as the Event Title.), the calendar updates  the event with the new description as is happening currently with this script.

Column D in the script below is empty to allow for insertion of an end date.

**Option 2:**  What do I need to change to have the script "look at" only those rows that have "Yes" in Column F.  This allows me to to the following:  Have my form insert a start date and end date and with formulas, evaluate all the days between.  Then output this result on a separate sheet and run the script on the sheet populated by formulas.

I have already created a separate sheet with the formulas in question.  The only problem I am having is that the script evaluates even the "empty" rows and takes forever to run, usually timing out before it is completed.  I would need it to "look at" only the rows with "Yes" in Column E.  This is a messier approach from a spreadsheet perspective, but perhaps easier approach from a scripting perspective.

**My current script is below.**

```
function updateCal() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarID");
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Entries");
  const [, ...rows] = data.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(([eventtitle, eventdescription, eventdate, , color]) => { // Now [eventtitle, eventdescription, eventdate] ?
    console.log(eventdate + eventtitle + eventdescription)
    const eventdate1 = new Date(eventdate)
    const events = cal.getEventsForDay(eventdate1);
    if (events.length == 0 || (events.length > 0 && !events.some(e => e.getTitle() == eventtitle) && !events.some(e => e.getDescription() == eventdescription))) {
      cal.createAllDayEvent(eventtitle, eventdate1, { description: eventdescription }).setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor[color]);
    } else {
      events.forEach(e => {
        if (e.getTitle() == eventtitle && e.getDescription() != eventdescription) {
          e.setDescription(eventdescription).setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor[color]);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my Spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet]

And here is my Calendar:

[image: Calendar]

Thanks to @GiselleValladares, I have now reached this point:

```
function updateCal() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarID");
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Entries");
  const [, ...rows] = data.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(([eventtitle, eventdescription, eventdate, , color]) => { // Now [eventtitle, eventdescription, eventdate] ?
    console.log(eventdate + eventtitle + eventdescription)
    const eventdate1 = new Date(eventdate);

    // new variable for the end Date
    // To make it so that the users add the exact date the event ends in the form
    // And add the following to variables to make sure the event is added correctly.
    const millisPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2; 
    const eventEndDate = new Date(eventEnddate.getTime() + millisPerDay);

    

    const events = cal.getEventsForDay(eventdate1);
    if (events.length == 0 || (events.length > 0 && !events.some(e => e.getTitle() == eventtitle) && !events.some(e => e.getDescription() == eventdescription))) {

      // add the end date to the code
      cal.createAllDayEvent(eventtitle, eventdate1, eventEndDate,{ description: eventdescription }).setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.color);
    } else {
      events.forEach(e => {
        if (e.getTitle() == eventtitle && e.getDescription() != eventdescription) {
          e.setDescription(eventdescription).setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.color);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I have modified my dates and have now set them for one day later.  See Spreadsheet screenshot.  The result is that single-day events are now showing up in the calendar correctly as single-day events.  However, multiple-day events are ending one day too early.

[image: Spreadsheet 2]

[image: Calendar 2]

I would have expected Don Drysdale to show up on May 9th thru May 12th.

Comment: What do you mean by `allow multiple days to be added or updated on Google Calendar?` Are you referring to make Recurrent event? Or make the event to last more than 1 day?  Can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Modifying question now.

Comment: Thank you @GiselleValladares.  I have modified question in the hopes of making my quest more clear.

Comment: I have also added another option to solving the issue.

Comment: Let me know if that helps. If you do not want to update the form, you will need to do more complex changes to the code, unless the number of days is a fix number. In that case, let me know, and I can update the code with that number of days, instead of updating the form.

Comment: Did the code work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify the form to have a `start date` and an `end date` and pass this information to the creation of the event. Or at least the `end date` since you are already using `const eventdate1 = new Date(eventdate)`.

You will need to add an extra date for the `end date` since if you added the event from `July 19, 2023` to `July 20, 2023` the event will be created only for `July 19, 2023`. Since base on the Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle,-startdate,-enddate,-options):

> The date when the event ends (only the day is used; the time is
> ignored). **The end date is exclusive**.

After that, you can modify the script like this:

```
function updateCal() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarID");
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Entries");
  const [, ...rows] = data.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(([eventtitle, eventdescription, eventdate, , color]) => { // Now [eventtitle, eventdescription, eventdate] ?
    console.log(eventdate + eventtitle + eventdescription)
    const eventdate1 = new Date(eventdate);

    // new variable for the end Date
    // To make it so that the users add the exact date the event ends in the form
    // And add the following to variables to make sure the event is added correctly.
    const millisPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; 
    const eventEndDate = new Date(eventEnddate.getTime() + millisPerDay);

    

    const events = cal.getEventsForDay(eventdate1);
    if (events.length == 0 || (events.length > 0 && !events.some(e => e.getTitle() == eventtitle) && !events.some(e => e.getDescription() == eventdescription))) {

      // add the end date to the code
      cal.createAllDayEvent(eventtitle, eventdate1, eventEndDate,{ description: eventdescription }).setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.color);
    } else {
      events.forEach(e => {
        if (e.getTitle() == eventtitle && e.getDescription() != eventdescription) {
          e.setDescription(eventdescription).setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.color);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**Update:**

Test with:

```
const millisPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
```

or

```
const millisPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2;
```

**New Update**

I create a table on Google Sheets, just like the one you posted.

[image: test]

Here is the complete code, I rename some variables and made some changes. And it's working for me:

```
function updateCal() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarID");
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Entries");
  const [, ...rows] = data.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(([eventtitle, eventdescription, eventStartdate, eventEnddate, color]) => { // Now [eventtitle, eventdescription, eventdate, eventEnddate] ?

    const eventStartDate1 = new Date(eventStartdate);

    // new variable for the end Date
    // To make it so that the users add the exact date the event ends in the form
    // And add the following to variables to make sure the event is added correctly.
    const millisPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    const eventEndDate = new Date(eventEnddate.getTime() + millisPerDay);

    const events = cal.getEventsForDay(eventStartDate1);

    if (events.length == 0 || (events.length > 0 && !events.some(e => e.getTitle() == eventtitle) && !events.some(e => e.getDescription() == eventdescription))) {
      

      // add the end date to the c
      cal.createAllDayEvent(eventtitle, eventStartDate1, eventEndDate, { description: eventdescription }).setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor[color]);

    } else {
      events.forEach(e => {
        if (e.getTitle() == eventtitle && e.getDescription() != eventdescription) {
          e.setDescription(eventdescription).setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor[color]);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This is my data:
[image: sample]

And this is how it looks in my calendar:
[image: Calendar]

Comment: Am getting error:  Exception: Invalid argument: color
(anonymous) @ Add/Update.gs:25
(anonymous) @ Add/Update.gs:23
updateCal @ Add/Update.gs:5  whereas before I had no issue with changing a color.

Comment: If I remove .setColor from the Script, the script runs successfully, but the calendar shows the multiple-day event starting and ending one day earlier than expected.  And of course, now I can't set the color of the event.

Comment: Without the changes I suggested, do you have an error?

Comment: I get no error with my original script.  And the dates enter correctly.  However, I am limited to only writing a one-day event to Google Calendar.

Comment: I updated the code, could you try once more?

Comment: Exception: Invalid argument: color
(anonymous) @ Add/Update.gs:25
(anonymous) @ Add/Update.gs:23
updateCal @ Add/Update.gs:5

Comment: Same color error.

Comment: I think I know which is the issue, the problem might be that the column where the color is located change, can you add a table of how your data is located in the Google sheet?

Comment: You're right.  It did change.  I added a column to convert to dates to fix an earlier error.  Let me try this again.

Comment: Deleted the column.  Added "eventEnddate" after "eventdate" to "rows.forEach" line.  Color is now showing up correctly.  Only issue is all events start and end one day early.  What did we need to do to fix that?

Comment: The `millisPerDay` should have taken care of that. Could you test with both options I just posted to see if one of that helps.

Comment: The end date is now correct.  The start date is a day early.  One day events now become two day events.

Comment: The `millisPerDay` should only be added to the `endEndDate`.

Comment: Have done so.  Added an extra day to the end date for single days.  Corrected the problem of multiple days.   Now only showing single days.  However, showing one day less on multiple day event.  End date ends an extra day early.  Don Drysdale in Spreadsheet says Start Date:  5/9/2023 and End Date 5/13/2023.  In Calendar, it shows that he is Off from 5/9/2023 thru 5/11/2023.

Comment: Could you update the question with the new code with all the changes made, how the event is being created and how it should be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254585/discussion-between-giselle-valladares-and-scriptingnovice).

Comment: Thank you.  Working now.  I did have to change my spreadsheet time settings to an hour earlier for it to record on the correct day.   Not quite sure why my spreadsheet and calendar are not in sync. But the days are now consistent.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Since this was apparently part of my issue and at the risk of being banned because I can't seem to write a well-received question, I have asked why there is a discrepancy between Google Sheets and Script Projects/ Calendar Timezone settings here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76779674/why-are-the-timezone-settings-on-my-spreadsheet-different-from-the-timezone-sett