# Why is Central Time on my Spreadsheet an hour different from Central Time on my Script Project and Google Calendar?

Tags: google-sheets, timezone, google-calendar-api

The Timezone Settings on my Google Spreadsheet are:  GMT-06:00 Central Time.

[image: Google Spreadsheet Timezone]

However, the Timezone settings on my Script Project and the Timezone Settings on my Google Calendar are: GMT-05:00 Central Time (Chicago).

[image: Script Project Timezone]
[image: Google Calendar Timezone]

Why is there a one hour discrepancy when both are United States Central Time?

Has anyone else experienced this issue or know the cause?

I believe this was partly the cause of my spreadsheet not sending data to the Calendar correctly here: [How Can I Add/Update Events Spanning Multiple Days to Google Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76721642/how-can-i-add-update-events-spanning-multiple-days-to-google-calendar)

Comment: I never notice that, I think it is a bug, since I have the same issue with 3 different accounts (2 Workspace and 1 personal account). I guess one of them got stock in Daylight saving or something.  Furthermore, I also found this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62215981) with the same issue. It's kinda old, but it was assigned this year. Maybe you can add a comment with this information there.

Comment: If you have Google Workspace, you can also create a case and report the issue directly by following [these steps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10759436).

Comment: Thank you.  I was wondering if it was a bug.

Comment: submit a bug report this isnt really programming related.

Comment: At @GiselleValladares recommendation, I have now done so.  It is related to a programming issue in regard to a script sending data from Google Sheets to Google Calendar.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76721642/how-can-i-add-update-events-spanning-multiple-days-to-google-calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this answer for visibly, since it was answered under the comments.

The issue is related to a bug, I found some of them under the [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=timezone%20issue%20one%20hour%20delay). It seems related to the `Daylight saving` time zone not updating properly.

The best solution at the moment is to report the issue to Google by [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) or by contacting [Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10759436) directly (if you have a Workspace account), since it will be faster than the issue tracker.

Comment: Have reported issue to Google as recommended.  Thank you.